# TypeScript declare reference throws error

Tags: typescript, declare

I want to understand the concept behind the `declare` keyword in practice, and I have tried to run [Reusable Types (Interfaces)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#reusable-types-interfaces) example:

```js
interface GreetingSettings {
  greeting: string;
  duration?: number;
  color?: string;
}

declare function greet(setting: GreetingSettings): void;

greet({
  greeting: "hello world",
  duration: 4000
});
```

But I get an error: `greet is not defined`

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOJQhMoDmBlLbEHAZ2QG8AoZZHDLXALmRLClwG5rkATAVyhxsAexAB+ZiD4BbAEbQuNBMIA2wqBJZtOlAL6UeEBCrgZkMPiAQiQtemAAUJQkzT3cBMEVIBKZgDdhYB4uSjpMRyoacIZiZgAiAAsIFTVkAHd1FR54gBpufkEbZgAWAAYKvR9QoA)

Is this the expected behavior of the `declare` keyword? If yes, what should I do that I would not get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the expected behavior of the declare keyword?

Yes. The purpose of `declare` is to tell TypeScript that something *already exists* and what its shape is. For example, there's a `declare` for `setTimeout` in the browser environment to tell TypeScript that the browser provides that function. `declare` doesn't create anything at runtime, it's purely to associate type information for TypeScript with something created elsewhere. (I'd say this isn't astonishingly-well documented [or I just can't find it], but it is covered in part [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html) and elsewhere in the part of the handbook.)

In your case, it would appear that `greet` does not already exist, so calling it gives you a runtime error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to clarify it further, I tried to define `greet` in this way `const greet = (setting: GreetingSettings): void => {
  //...
}`. Not runtime does not give any error but now I get IDE shows `Duplicate identifier 'greet'.` It is possible to declare and define a function with the same name in the same file?

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas - If you're creating the function in TypeScript code, there's normally no need to use `declare`; TypeScript already knows about the function. `declare` is for when you have functions defined outside what TypeScript can see. So just remove your `declare` for `greet` entirely, the `const greet = ...` does the job. :-)